# avro nested scheme multiple subrecords

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro

i have a problem regarding my avro scheme. This is my code i wrote for testing:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("user.avsc").read())
writer = DataFileWriter(open("users.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
writer.append({"count" : 5, "cvList" : {"id" : 5}})
writer.close()
```

The schema:

```
{
  "name" : "cv",
  "type" : "record",
  "fields" : [
    {"name" : "count", "type" : "int"},
     {"name" : "cvList",
      "type": {
        "name" : "cvData",
        "type" : "record",
        "fields" : [
          {"name" : "id", "type" : "int"}
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to do the following:
append count (the number of cvLists coming later) and then i want to be able to add a variable number of id's in cvList. I can add one count and one id, but i am not able to append multiple id's. I guess i have to rewrite the scheme but i have no clue how.

Grüße

Marius

Comment: Do you able to solve this issue Marius? If yes can you please let me know how you solved it?

Comment: Its been a while but i solved the problem however i currently dont have time but maybe this helps you: http://apache-avro.679487.n3.nabble.com/Schema-for-array-of-records-td2710382.html. If not i will try to show you how to solve it.